# Prediction intervals for simple/baseline forecasts

Tags: time-series, forecasting, prediction-interval

I'm reading [this](https://otexts.com/fpp3/prediction-intervals.html), and I don't understand how the prediction intervals are calculated for the baseline forecast methods. I agree that we can estimate the SD of the sample from the known residuals
$$ \begin{equation}
  \hat{\sigma} = \sqrt{\frac{1}{T-K-M}\sum_{t=1}^T e_t^2}, \tag{5.1}
\end{equation}$$

Where $K$ is number of parameters, and $M$ is number of missing values. And I agree that intuitively they should grow with longer forecast (grow with $h$). But I'm not sure how you actually arrive to these quantities? (Assuming normally distributed and uncorrelated residuals).

[image]

Can anyone show the math behind this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We assume that the residuals from the method are uncorrelated and homoscedastic, with mean 0 and variance $\sigma^2$. We don't need to assume normality. Let $y_1,\dots,y_T$ denote the time series observations, and let $\hat{y}_{T+h|T}$ be the estimated forecast mean (or point forecast). Then we can write
$$
y_t = \hat{y}_{t|t-1} + \varepsilon_t
$$
where $\varepsilon$ is a white noise process. Let $\hat\sigma_h^2$ be the estimated $h$-step forecast variance.

### Random walk/Naive method

For a random walk, the equation above suggests that the appropriate model is
$$y_t = y_{t-1} + \varepsilon_t.$$
Therefore
\begin{align*}
y_{T+1} &= y_T + \varepsilon_T \\
y_{T+2} &= y_{T+1} + \varepsilon_{T+1}  = y_T + \varepsilon_T + \varepsilon_{T+1}\\
\vdots \\
y_{T+h} &= y_T + \sum_{i=1}^h \varepsilon_{T+i},
\end{align*}
and so
\begin{align*}
\hat{y}_{T+h|T} &= E(y_{T+h|T}) = y_T\\
\text{and}\qquad
\hat{\sigma}^2_{h} &= V(y_{T+h|T}) = h\sigma^2
\end{align*}

### Seasonal naive method

Here the model is
$$y_t = y_{t-m} + \varepsilon_t,$$
where $m$ is the seasonal period. Thus
\begin{align*}
y_{T+1} &= y_{T+1-m} + \varepsilon_{T+1} \\
y_{T+2} &= y_{T+2-m} + \varepsilon_{T+2} \\
\vdots \\
y_{T+m} &= y_{T} + \varepsilon_{T+m} \\
y_{T+m+1} &= y_{T+1} + \varepsilon_{T+m+1} = y_{T+1-m} + \varepsilon_{T+1} + \varepsilon_{T+m+1}\\
\vdots\\
y_{T+2m} &= y_{T+m} + \varepsilon_{T+2m} = y_{T} + \varepsilon_{T+m} + \varepsilon_{T+2m}\\
y_{T+2m+1} &= y_{T+m+1} + \varepsilon_{T+2m+1} = y_{T+1-m} + \varepsilon_{T+1} + \varepsilon_{T+m+1} + \varepsilon_{T+2m+1}\\
\vdots\\
y_{T+h} &= y_{T+h-m(k+1)} + \sum_{i=0}^{k} \varepsilon_{T+h+m(i-k)},
\end{align*}
where $k$ is the integer part of $(h-1) /m$ (i.e., the number of complete years in the forecast period prior to time $T+h$).
Therefore
\begin{align*}
\hat{y}_{T+h|T} &= E(y_{T+h|T}) = y_{T+h-m(k+1)}\\
\text{and}\qquad
\hat{\sigma}^2_{h} &= V(y_{T+h|T}) = (k+1)\sigma^2
\end{align*}

### Mean method

The model underpinning the mean method is
$$y_t = c + \varepsilon_t$$
for some constant $c$ to be estimated. The least-squares estimate of $c$ is the mean, $\hat{c} = \bar{y} = (y_1+\dots+y_T)/T.$ Thus,
\begin{align*}
y_{T+1} &= c + \varepsilon_{T+1} \\
y_{T+2} &= c + \varepsilon_{T+1} \\
\vdots \\
y_{T+h} &= c + \varepsilon_{T+h}.
\end{align*}
Therefore
\begin{align*}
\hat{y}_{T+h|T} &= E(y_{T+h|T}) = \hat{c} = \bar{y}\\
\text{and}\qquad
\hat{\sigma}^2_{h} &= V(y_{T+h|T}) = V(\hat{c}) + \sigma^2 = (T^{-1} + 1)\sigma^2
\end{align*}

### Drift method

For a random walk with drift
$$y_{t} = c + y_{t-1} + \varepsilon_t.$$
Therefore,
\begin{align*}
y_{T+1} &= c + y_T + \varepsilon_T \\
y_{T+2} &= 2 + y_{T+1} + \varepsilon_{T+1}  = 2c + y_T + \varepsilon_T + \varepsilon_{T+1}\\
\vdots \\
y_{T+h} &= hc + y_T + \sum_{i=1}^h \varepsilon_{T+i}.
\end{align*}
Now the least squares estimate of $c$ is $\hat{c} = (y_{T}-y_1)/(T-1)$.
Therefore
\begin{align*}
\hat{y}_{T+h|T} &= E(y_{T+h|T}) = h\hat{c} + y_T\\
\text{and}\qquad
\hat{\sigma}^2_{h} &= V(y_{T+h|T}) = V(\hat{c}) + h\sigma^2 = \frac{h^2\sigma^2}{T-1} + h\sigma^2.
\end{align*}
I've also cross-posted this answer on my blog at https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/forecasting_variances.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I think you need the normality assumption for the 1.96 in the prediction interval.

Comment: Yes, that is needed for the PI, but not for the derivations in my answer.